# multiple (and wrong size) images download with srcset

Tags: html, google-chrome, responsive-design, srcset

I tried to use `srcset` in my project for requesting and downloading proper image depend on the browser size but I get the wrong result from Network tab in Chrome Developer Tools.

here is my code

```
<img srcset="
    {{url('/cdn/images/320x700/hotel/hotel-cover-wide-min.jpg')}} 320w,
    {{url('/cdn/images/845x450/hotel/hotel-cover-wide-min.jpg')}} 845w,
    {{url('/cdn/images/1519x670/hotel/hotel-cover-wide-min.jpg')}} 1519w"
    sizes="
    (max-width:767px) 100vw,
    (min-width: 768px) and (max-width: 991px) 100vw,
    (min-width: 992px) and (max-width: 1199px) 100vw,
    (min-width: 1200px) 100vw
     "
    src="{{asset('images/hotel/hotel-cover-wide-min.jpg')}}"
    alt="">
```

I used **Bootstrap** media queries and I expect to download the smallest(320*700) image in mobile (google chrome device simulator) 4s(320*480):
I expect this image to load:

`'/cdn/images/320x700/hotel/hotel-cover-wide-min.jpg'`

but this image load in network tab:

`'/cdn/images/845x450/hotel/hotel-cover-wide-min.jpg'`

and also in some situations, 2 images loaded at the same time in the network tab!
[image: 2 images downloaded in network tab (iPhone 4s)]

**it really doesn't go well in any size**

I appreciate if anyone helps me with this issue

I use Chrome Canary Version 73 by the way